# Is there a way to create a universal singleton for a generic class which has an identity method?

Tags: java, generics

I have a simple interface:

```
public interface Constraint<T> {
    T constrain(T unconstrainedValue);
}
```

and I want to create an `UNCONSTRAINED` singleton that I can use for any type... is there a way to do this without creating separate objects for each type?

```
static class NoConstraint<T> implements Constraint<T> {
    @Override public T constrain(T unconstrainedValue) { return unconstrainedValue; }
}
```

Comment: why does your NoConstraint class model have a static modifier? Is it supposed to be an inner class?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using unsafe casts, which you know will be safe:

```
static class NoConstraint<T> implements Constraint<T> {
    private static final Constraint rawInstance = new NoConstraint();

    public static <T> Constraint<T> instance() {
        @SupressWarnings("unchecked")
        Constraint<T> generic = rawInstance;
        return generic;
    }

    @Override
    public T constrain(T unconstrainedValue) {
        return unconstrainedValue;
    }
}
```

Needless to say, you should only do this if you're proven to yourself that it's always safe (which in this case is probably pretty easy to do).

This is not an uncommon trick in situations like this. For instance, [`Collections.emptyList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Collections.java#4478) (and similar methods in that class) use this technique.

Note also that the `T` in the `instance()` method is *different* from the `T` in `Constraint<T>`, despite the fact that they share the same name. The Constraint's `T` is only available in instance context, not in static context, so we have to declare a generic parameter for the static method. Most of the time, shadowing names like this is dangerous; in cases like this, I find it useful, as a visual reminder that both `T`s are closely connected as far as the typical user is concerned.

Comment: return T won't work because you need to return an object not a type. perhaps you mean return unconstrainedValue. The same issue is in the original question.

Comment: @WillShackleford Ah yes, thanks -- I just copypasta'ed that bit. :) Will fix it.

Comment: You should add a private constructor so the class can't be instantiated elsewhere